# OOP Query function

Tags: php, oop, func

I'm sorry if this may sound like a really dumb question but I'm just beginning the grasp the concept of object oriented programming and I am kind of confused about the singleton pattern for php.

How would I incorporate a query along with saving the results from the rows fetched saved as variables into the singleton pattern?

For example, how would the code below get incorporated?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email1'])."'";
$result   = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$number   = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i   = 0;

while ($i < $number) 
{

    $first_name  = mysql_result($result,$i,"first_name"); 
    $last_name  = mysql_result($result,$i,"last_name");
    $state   = mysql_result($result,$i,"home_state");
    $id_district  = mysql_result($result,$i,"district");
    $political_views = mysql_result($result,$i,"political_views");
    $first_issue  = mysql_result($result,$i,"first_issue");
    $second_issue  = mysql_result($result,$i,"second_issue");
    $third_issue  = mysql_result($result,$i,"third_issue");
    $email   = mysql_result($result,$i,"email");
    $iStand   = mysql_result($result,$i,"iStand");
    $photo   = mysql_result($result,$i,"photo");
    $code   = mysql_result($result,$i,"code");
    $changed   = mysql_result($result,$i,"changed");
    $mem_ID          = mysql_result($result,$i,"member_ID");
    $pass   = mysql_result($result,$i,"password");
    $privacy   = mysql_result($result,$i,"privacy");
    $since   = mysql_result($result,$i,"invite_date");
    $nombre   = mysql_result($result,$i,"peer_name");

    $i++;
  }
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but what is this code in the first place? Why would you fetch multiple rows just to put the values from only the LAST row into variables? Why assign each column to a variable separately instead of just asking for the whole row as an associative array (mysql_fetch_array)? This code should not exist!

Comment: There is only one row that is fetched from the db since the email field is unique and hence no two users can have the same email.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't need a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

A Singleton pattern has a specific purpose:

> [the singleton pattern is a design pattern used to implement the mathematical concept of a singleton, by restricting the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

This isn't appropriate for the functionality that you've presented above.

A Singleton pattern would be used, for example, when creating a system-wide settings class. The Singleton prevents itself from being instantiated more than once (or, at all) and instead provides a single place to get and set setting information.

Comment: You could add that the Singleton is an AntiPattern that should be avoided.